# How to check if a Delphi form exists

Tags: delphi

I am using strings to create Available forms, but I cannot figure out how to test if a form has already been created. I only want a single instance of each form.

```
Procedure TMainForm.CreateFormFromName(const FormName:String);
var
 fc:TFormClass;
 f:Tform
begin
  fc := TFormClass(FindClass(FormName));
  f := fc.Create(Application);
  f.show
end;
 
Procedure TMainForm.FormCreate(Sender:TObject);
begin
  RegisterClass(TfrmTest);
end;
```

I can send a string to CreateForm and it does create the form. But how do I lock out a second attempt to create the same form?

Answer (score 8):

As the Owner of the forms may not be `Application` in all situations, iterating over `Screen.Forms/Screen.FormCount` may be the better approach.

In case the forms are not derived from `TForm` but only from `TCustomForm` there also is `Screen.CustomForms/Screen.CustomFormCount`.

Answer (score 4):

Owner of all your forms is `Application`, so just check if it already constains the form with necessary class:

```
function IsFormAlreadyCreated(AFormClass : TClass) : boolean;
 var
   i : integer;
   cmp : TComponent;
 begin
   Result := false;
   for i := 0 to Application.ComponentCount - 1 do
   begin
     if Application.Components[i].ClassType = AFormClass then
     begin
       Result := true;
       break;
     end;
   end;
 end;
```

Call it with the class you want to search, f.e.:

```
if IsFormAlreadyCreated(TForm1) then ...
```